# How to Install Visual Studio Extension into specific folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Is it possible to change the default location of the folder where all Visual Studio extensions are installed?

I noticed that all extensions are installed inside `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs` folder.

I want this because I want to upload all the dlls to the VSTS so that we don't need to install the Visual studio extension to each Developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. Also, just have an extension in source control doesn't mean it's going to be auto-installed either. Not even non-SCM solutions such as NuGet allow for extension deployment and installation